# .NET 8 Blazor: When I publish the application all that loads is a blank white page

Tags: .net, blazor, .net-8.0

I have a .NET 8 app that has auto render mode (server and web assembly). It works fine when I run it through the VS but when I publish it or run through the dotnet command it just shows a white page. No elements are loaded inside the body.

I tried making sure I have all the runtimes for the .NET 8. I tried running it on a different machine but it does not run.

EDIT

After commenting some components the UI showed, but it behaves as an MVC app. Every click just sends a request to the server that replies with the whole page. No interactivity.

After more investigation I found out that all the libraries that are injected are not found when I publish they dont't work, libraries like (Blazored.Localstorage, Blazored.Modal,Localization)

```js
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: VTable setup of type Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.ResourceManagerStringLocalizer failed
System.TypeLoadException: VTable setup of type Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.ResourceManagerStringLocalizer failed
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory.Create(Type )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.StringLocalizer`1[[UI.Shared.Localization.SharedResource, UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]..ctor(IStringLocalizerFactory factory)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InterpretedInvoke_Constructor(Object obj, IntPtr* args)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeDirectByRefWithFewArgs(Object , Span`1 , BindingFlags )
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithOneArg(Object , BindingFlags , Binder , Object[] , CultureInfo )
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags , Binder , Object[] , CultureInfo )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite , RuntimeResolverContext )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite , RuntimeResolverContext )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite , RuntimeResolverContext )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite , ServiceProviderEngineScope )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(ServiceIdentifier , ServiceProviderEngineScope )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<CreatePropertyInjector>g__Initialize|1(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IComponent component)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.InstantiateComponent(IServiceProvider , Type , IComponentRenderMode , Nullable`1 )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InstantiateChildComponentOnFrame(RenderTreeFrame[] , Int32 , Int32 )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewComponentFrame(DiffContext& , Int32 )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewSubtree(DiffContext& , Int32 )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(DiffContext& , Int32 )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(DiffContext& , Int32 )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& , Int32 , Int32 , Int32 , Int32 )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff(Renderer , RenderBatchBuilder , Int32 , ArrayRange`1 , ArrayRange`1 )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder , RenderFragment , Exception& )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
```

Comment: What errors are you seeing in the console?

Comment: Thats the problem i got no errors in the console

Comment: after commenting some components the UI showed, but it behaves as an MVC app, every click just sends request to the server that replies with the whole page. No interactivity

Comment: What can you see in the F12 Network tab? The error is about Localization , do you use that?

Comment: Yes i use localization, but there nothing in the network tab regarding the localization other than the DLLs loading and it is successful

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with my blazor application.

The first one was that after navigation by link blank page was shown. I needed a page refresh for this page to display correctly. This effect was caused by wrong placement of MudBlazor declaration tags: `<MudThemeProvider/> <MudDialogProvider/> <MudSnackbarProvider/>` These tags should be in `<head>` section of html page, not inside `<body>` element.

Second problem was be with hosting WCF services within blazor app. The problem showed up when I published my blazor application. The published self hosted exe application raised some exceptions. In this case I had to use `--urls http://localhost:443` as command line parameter of self hosted app for resolve this issue.